# Convert recordset into an array

Tags: arrays, excel, recordset, vba

I would like to convert a recordset `rs` into an array so that I can use it in further  code. 
 `rs` can have variable rows and variable columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ADODB` it is as simple as:

```
Dim ret As Variant

ret = rs.GetRows '~~> assuming rs object is populated and set

Debug.Print Lbound(ret, 1), Ubound(ret, 1) '~~> bounds of 1st dimension
Debug.Print Lbound(ret, 2), Ubound(ret, 2) '~~> bounds of 2nd dimension
```